# my .length method returns 0 when i has 9 divs in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

```
const boxes = {
  height: 220,
  width: 220,
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  borderRadius: '25%',
};
const main = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'auto auto auto',
  gridGap: '20px',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  marginTop: '20px',
};

const box = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');
console.log(box.length);

class Easy extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="easy-game">
        <div className="Easy-main" style={main}>
          <div style={boxes} className="boxes" />
          <div style={boxes} className="boxes" />
          <div style={boxes} className="boxes" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Easy;
```

This is my Code and my .length method gives 0 in return while there are 3 divs using the same class I am starting in react so I can be wrong somewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your code runs before render, so there will be no element rendered**

Move it inside a `componentDidMount` which run after the initial render:

```
class Easy extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const box = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');  //<-- Move it here
    console.log(box.length);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="easy-game">
        <div className="Easy-main" style={main}>
          <div style={boxes} className="boxes" />
          <div style={boxes} className="boxes" />
          <div style={boxes} className="boxes" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```